# django CheckboxSelectMultiple: my checkboxes are not checked

Tags: django, checkbox, multiplechoicefield

I have a `ManyToManyField`, displayed with checkboxes. Checkboxes should be checked when my boolean field `share_data` is equal to one.

Here is the code:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    databases = models.ManyToManyField(Advertiser, null=True, blank=True, through='ShareDataToBrands')

    @property
    def share_to_brands_list(self):
        brands=[]
        for brand in ShareDataToBrands.objects.all():
            brands.append((brand.advertiser.id, brand.advertiser.brand_name, brand.share_data))
    return brands


class ShareDataToBrands(models.Model):
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant, blank=False, null=False)
    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(Advertiser, blank=False, null=False)
    share_data= models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.participant, self.advertiser, self.share_data


class ShareDataToBrandsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Participant
        fields = ('databases', )

    databases=forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShareDataToBrandsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        share_to_brands=self.instance.share_to_brands_list
        self.fields['databases'].choices=self.fields['databases'].choices=[(brand[0], brand[1]) for brand in share_to_brands]
        self.initial['databases']=[brand[2] for brand in share_to_brands]
        print(self.initial['databases'])
        for brand in self.instance.share_to_brands_list:
            print brand
```

The output:

```
[True, True, True]
(1L, u'my super brand', True)
(2L, u'new brand', True)
(3L, u'just my brand', True)
```

Currently, only the first checkbox is checked, even though all should be checked as seen in the output. What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think when setting initial values for a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget, you need to pass a list of *values* that should be checked, rather than a list of booleans for each option.  So doing `initial = [True,True,True]` doesn't get you the boxes checked.  You want to do something more like `initial = [1,2,3]`.

In your example, you might replace the relevant line with:

```
self.initial['databases']=[brand[0] for brand in share_to_brands if brand[2]]
```

Comment: it workkkkkkkssssssssssssss :). Thank you very much.